# What's the performance difference between Elasticsearch _all field search and multi-match

Tags: elasticsearch

I know Elasticsearch enables _all field as default. But for some reason (scoring) I don't want to use it. Instead I use multi_match, where I have almost 10 fields. Is the performance of multi_match worse than _all field? And how much?

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, it depends more on the query than on the field itself. I think, you are talking about `query_string` which by default use `_all` field.

That said, using `match` query (or `multi_match`) instead of `query_string` query will probably be faster. And using multi match on a list of fields than on `_all` field will probably be faster as match queries are optimized and uses the *best internal query* depending on the field and the query content themselves.

I can not tell how much it's faster. But, you can run test easily for your use case and measure that.

HTH